# How to define chirality for massive particles on the level of the states and not fields?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, parity, chirality

Textbooks often define chirality on the level of the *fields* but not on the level of the *states*. How does one define chirality on the level of one-particle *states*?

It is clear how one can define chirality on the level of *fields* $\psi^{\alpha}(x)$, as Lorentz indices such as $\alpha$ (which may be a vector index $\mu$ for a spin-1 massive field or a spinor index $\alpha$ for a spin-1/2 massive field) as these indices transform directly under the Lorentz group, and representations of the Lorentz group have a definite notion of handedness i.e. finite reps are classified by two half integers $(A,B)$ and the $(1/2,0)$ rep is said to be left handed and $(0,1/2)$ to be right handed. However it is unclear how there is a notion of handedness on the level of massive *states* $|p^{\mu},\sigma\rangle$. It is unclear because the states transform under representations of the little group, which for massive particles is $SO(3)$, and representations of $SO(3)$ by themselves do not have a notion of handedness.

Q: what is the definition of chirality purely on the level of the states?

Comment: There is none. States just don’t have chirality. Sometimes basic particle physics books try to say they do, by confusing chirality with helicity, but they’re wrong.

Comment: @knzhou I have never cheered at a comment before, but I'd feel remiss if I didn't on this one. I wish somebody could incorporate it in the suitable WP articles! As a short answer here, it  would be truly salutary.

Comment: Recommended reading: [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/498077) and [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/644322), both by @knzhou.